# League of Legends patcher crashes on playonlinux

Tags: wine, games, crash, playonlinux

Not sure if I'm posting in the right place and how many of you will have knowledge of playonlinux and LoL crashing, but here is the bug I posted to the playonlinux site and I figured I'd repost here to hope for results.

Running Ubuntu 15.10, trying to install League of Legends through playonlinux (newest version, used `apt-get playonlinux` and `apt-get wine`)

The patcher/launcher crashes during part 2/2 (Updating) at roughly 60% each time.

Have tried configuring LoL with following wine versions:

1.7.52-LeagueOfLegends5

1.7.52-LeagueOfLegends4

1.7.44-LeagueOfLegends3

1.7.33-LeagueOfLegends2

None of which worked, patcher takes around 10 minutes to get from 33% to 60% then crashes.

Crash says something about wine not working (can't remember exactly).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download playonlinux
2. Download LoL through playonlinux, choose wine version in the configuration
3. Follow the installing instructions
4. After finished installing, open the patcher to let the game download and patch it
5. Crashes at step 2/2 (Updating) at ~60%

Comment: Does the patch working with native Windows? I'd advice you to update to the PPA with latest wine, then to try again. If it still crashes, report a bug.

Comment: I found this to be helpful: https://github.com/TheUnnamedDude/pol_league_of_legends

Answer (score 0):

So that's simple, the problem is you don't have installed the Adobe Air PlayOnLinux component on your LoL instalation. I installed it this evening and voilà!! The installation succeeded the 60% and I've played the game 1 hour ago.

Try this and good luck >:D